# How to toggle visibility of links within a rails generated table?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to toggle the visibility of 2 different links (`send_email` and `email_sent`) in a table in my rails app.

```
<table >
<% @applications.each do |application| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="mailto:grant@example.com" class="send_email">Invite for an interview</a>

   <a href="" class="email_sent">Undo</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

In my css I have

```
.email_sent{display: none;}
```

Here is my javascript

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
 $(function(){
  $('.send_email > a').click(function(){
   $('.send_email').hide();
   $('.email_sent').show();
  });
  $('.email_sent > a').click(function(){
   $('.send_email').show();
   $('.email_sent').hide();
  });
 });
<% end %>
```

The problem is that this code toggles all the `email_sent` and `send_email` links.

How can I adjust my code to only toggle the visibility of the links in a particular row?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working as you are using **Class** which is common in every row. Try giving it a unique id and use that inside javascript Eg:-

**I assume application holds array of DB records**

```
<table >
  <% @applications.each do |application| %>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <a href="mailto:grant@example.com" id="send_email_#{application.id}">Invite for an interview</a>
       <a href="" id="email_sent_#{application.id}">Undo</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

Then in javascript

```
<% @applications.each do |application| %>    
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    $("#send_email_#{application.id} a").click(function(){
      $("#send_email_#{application.id}").hide();
      $("#email_sent_#{application.id}").show();
    });
    $('#email_sent_#{application.id} a').click(function(){
      $('#send_email_#{application.id}').show();
      $('#email_sent_#{application.id}').hide();
    });
<% end %>
```